# Cassandra remote connection not working on Ubuntu

Tags: azure, ubuntu, cassandra, virtual-machine

I have cassandra set up on an Azure VM and it works find locally. However, I'm trying to connect to it from another machine so I modified the yaml file but it returns unresolvable contact point error. I'm connecting to cassendra with this python script. I also allowed the port on Azure.

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

try:
    cluster = Cluster(['ip of vm'])
        session = cluster.connect()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Configured the cassendra.yaml file according to this

```
start_rpc: true

rpc_address: 0.0.0.0

broadcast_rpc_address: [node-ip]

listen_address: [node-ip]

seed_provider:
  - class_name: ...
    - seeds: "[node-ip]"
```

Comment: What do you mean works fine locally? And do you want to connect it from another VM in the same vnet or subnet?

Comment: it only works when connecting to localhost

Comment: You need to provide more messages about what I ask in the comment.

Comment: Any more message you can provide? And do you add the NSG rule to allow the traffic for the right port that the Cassandra listen to?